# Increasing shared_buffer > 25% of RAM crashes Postgres, Ubuntu reports plenty of "available" memory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

I have a not-for-profit website with pretty low traffic (a few hundred users), but it's backed by a fairly busy PostGIS database.  Most of the database activity comes from harvesting rainfall and stream flow data from government APIs and then summarizing that data (how much rain has fallen at each rain gauge in the past 3, 6, 12, hours, etc). Since I don't charge for the site, I'm trying to keep my hosting costs as low as possible. I'm in the process of migrating it to a new Ubuntu VPS with 1GB of RAM. Hence, I've followed the general rule of thumb setting Postgres' shared_memory to 250MB (25% of total RAM). Granted, this server isn't totally dedicated to Postgres, but my web traffic is pretty low.

Here's a fairly typical RAM situation on this server (low activity at the moment)

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1024         228           0         379         795         656
Swap:          1024         676         347
Total:         2048         905         347
```

All of the heavily used indexes have very high hit rates (>0.945), but some of the tables data are much lower: a few under 0.5, but they're not used all that heavily and I suspect that the most recent and most queried data. So no show stoppers, yet. When I query pg_buffercache, it shows 247MB in the buffer. This is the only database on the server.  So I think it could benefit from more shared_buffers.

So I upped the share_buffer to 350MB and restarted the server. Not just Postgres, but the entire Ubuntu server. After reboot, I can't connect to Postgres via PgAdmin 4 (which is running on my desktop Ubuntu, NOT on the server). Then, some of my map layers (PostGIS tables) don't display on my OpenLayers map. When I paste some of the calls that OL is making to PG via a php script, it's returning 505 Internal Server Error. So I changed the buffer back to 250MB and restarted the server.  Everything was functioning again. I tried 300MB, but got the same exact symptoms.

So I looked into the PG logs:

```
2017-10-10 19:22:50.855 EDT [3485] FATAL:  could not map anonymous shared memory: Cannot allocate memory
2017-10-10 19:22:50.855 EDT [3485] HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory, swap space, or huge pages. To reduce the request size (currently 562085888 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
```

I'm fairly new to Linux and definitely new at Linux admin (my previous host managed the database and the server). From what I've read, Linux will cache a lot of it's internal files for faster performance, but it's supposed to relinquish some of that cache when applications demand it. That's the "buff/cache", right? And there should be 656MB of it "available", right? So why can't PG get 50 or 100MB of that?

Comment: If you don't have the memory, you shouldn't use it (shared memory is pinned) So: lower your shared_buffers setting. You could also lower work_mem and/or max_connections.

Comment: Have you examined my answer below. Did it help?

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel shared memory settings need to be updated using sysctl. The following will allow up to 16gb of shared memory, which will likely be enough.

```
 sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=17179869184
 sysctl -w kernel.shmall=4194304
```

for more info on these parameters see the following:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/kernel-resources.html
https://serverfault.com/questions/341680/postgresql-performance-adjusting-shmmax-and-shmall

Comment: I've added the above to /etc/sysctl.conf.  Below is the output of  ipcs -l  `------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 16777216
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 16777216
min seg size (bytes) = 1`  But I'm getting the same PG errors when I try to increase shared_buffer to 350MB or just 300MB

Comment: you may just be totally out of memory. What does top or other utility tell you about your available system memory. For a 1GB (very small) system, getting over 25% of memory towards buffers is going to be a tall order.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I often have over 500 MB in "available memory", as mentioned in my original post

Comment: What tool did you use to get the information you posted about your memory and swap usage?